# A new form for each dialog in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface

I was creating sixth form for a simple one digit user input and it got me wandering maybe there is an easier way to do this maybe there is a built in tool that would create dialogs in a similar fashion as error warnings.

Is there a simplified way to create basic UI dialogs using c++ in Visual Studio?

P.S. I could use the same form for more than one input operation but I have to get different type and size values so a bit of user input validation is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You might create one form which is capable of using a validation
  class or a list of rules which it validates. So you can use the same
  form for different validations.
- You might create one form and use this form as base class. Then
  implement the differences in derived classes
- You could of course also create a wizard which generates the basic
  code for you. This would be less elegant, but would decrease the time
  you need to create a form.

There is no "out-of-the-box" solution I know of which is capable of what you want, at least without or almost none effort.

Comment: Thanks for an answer maybe there is third party solution? Maybe a library or a VS plugin.

Comment: I added a third option which uses inheritance. This no library or plugin though ,)